# Android: Save Selected Contacts TO SQLite DataBase

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-listview, android-contacts

In my app, I am allowing user to select five contact(one by one) so that I can send a custom message to selected contacts. I want to save the selected contacts to the DataBase. When user clicks on "Pick Contact Button", it opens phone's contact book and the selected contact will get displayed in List View. Similarly, he can add 5 contacts for which I want to save them in DataBase. I have been able to write some code but don't how to save the contact.Please Help.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_message);

            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            /**
             * CRUD Operations
             * */
    //      Inserting Contacts
            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); 



            // Reading all contacts
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts.."); 
            List<ContactItems> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       

            for (ContactItems cn : contacts) {
                String log = "Id: "+cn.getType()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " + cn.getNumber();
                    // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Name: ", log);
        }
        /************************** saving custom message *****************************/

            // for saving text that user can change as per need
            final SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

            // loads the text that has been stored to SP and set it to Edit Text
            message.setText(preferences.getString("autoSave", ""));

            // adding addTextChangedListner() to the Edit Text View
            message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                        int count) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // saving text after it is changed by the user
                    preferences.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();

                }
            });
            ListView contactlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListitems);
            Resources res = getResources();
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, selectedContactList, res);
            contactlist.setAdapter(adapter);
/**************************EDIT******************************************/
contactlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String contactData = selectedContactList.get(arg2).toString();
        }
    }); 

        // defining button elements for picking contacts from phone-book
            btn_cntct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpickperson);
            btn_cntct.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (selectedContactList.size() < 5) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // using Intent for fetching contacts from phone-book
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUESTCODE);
                    } else {
                        // print toast for not allowing user to add more contacts
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "You Can Only Add 5 Contacts ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }

                }

            });

        }
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (data != null) {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.i("data", uri.toString());
                if (uri != null) {
                    Cursor c = null;
                    try {
                        c = getContentResolver()
                                .query(uri,
                                        new String[] {
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE },
                                        null, null, null);

                        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                            final ContactItems item = new ContactItems(
                                    c.getString(0), c.getString(1), c.getInt(2));
                            item.setName(c.getString(0));
                            item.setNumber(c.getString(1));
                            item.setType(c.getInt(2));
                            selectedContactList.add(item);
                            Set<ContactItems> s = new TreeSet<ContactItems>(
                                    new Comparator<ContactItems>() {

                                        @Override
                                        public int compare(ContactItems o1,
                                                ContactItems o2) {
                                            // for preventing duplicacy of contacts
                                            // and calling toast
                                            if (o1.number.equals(o2.number)) {
                                                Toast.makeText(
                                                        getApplicationContext(),
                                                        "Selected Number Already Exists",
                                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            } else {

                                            }
                                            return o1.getNumber().compareTo(
                                                    o2.getNumber());

                                        }
                                    });

                            s.addAll(selectedContactList);
                            selectedContactList.clear();
                            selectedContactList.addAll(s);
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            // save the task list to preference

                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (c != null) {
                            c.close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

ContactItems.java

```
public class ContactItems   {
    String name = "";
    String number = "";
    int type = 0;

    public ContactItems(String name, String number, int type) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ContactItems(Parcel source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.name = source.readString();
        this.number = source.readString();
        this.type = source.readInt();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }



    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ContactItems> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ContactItems>() {

        @Override
        public ContactItems createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new ContactItems(source);
        }

        @Override
        public ContactItems[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ContactItems[size];
        }

    };
}
```

DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactManager";
    // contact table name
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
    // contacts table column names
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_CONACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONACTS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

    // Adding new contact
    void addContact(ContactItems contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getNumber()); // Contact Phone

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single contact
    ContactItems getContact(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        ContactItems contact = new ContactItems(cursor.getString(2),
                cursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        // return contact
        return contact;
    }

    // Getting All Contacts
    public List<ContactItems> getAllContacts() {
        List<ContactItems> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactItems>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ContactItems contact = new ContactItems(null);
                contact.setType(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                contact.setNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                contactList.add(contact);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return contactList;
    }

    // Updating single contact
    public int updateContact(ContactItems contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getType()) });
    }

    // Deleting single contact
    public void deleteContact(ContactItems contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getType()) });
        db.close();
    }

    // Getting contacts Count
    public int getContactsCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
    }

}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<ContactItems> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    public Resources res;
    // ListModel tempValues=null;
    int i = 0;
    String selectedNum = " ";

    /************* CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ContactItems> d,
            Resources resLocal) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        res = resLocal;

        /*********** Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if (data.size() <= 0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder {

        public TextView text;
        public TextView textNumber;

        public ImageView image;

    }

    /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
    @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final int pos = position;
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        // check if converView is null, if it is null it probably means
        if (convertView == null) {

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlistitem, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/
            // if it is not null, just reuse it from the recycler
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.textNumber = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
            holder.image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.deleteimage);

            /************ Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

        if (data.size() <= 0) {

            holder.text.setText("Add Contacts");
            holder.textNumber.setText(" ");
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        } else {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/

            /************ Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText("" + data.get(position).getName());

            holder.textNumber.setText("" + data.get(position).getNumber());
            holder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("delete_button",
                    null, null));

            holder.image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            activity);
                    build.setTitle("Delete");
                    build.setMessage("Are You Sure");
                    build.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    data.remove(pos);
                                    MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });

                    /*
                     * data.remove(pos);
                     * MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     */
                    build.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    build.show();
                }

            });
            /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/

        }
        // return the view for a single item in the listview
        return vi;
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider making the question more specific: What's the exact problem you're having. As of now itseems to be a wall of code with a request of "debug and complete this for me" which is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @laalto let me make it more clear. When i click "Pick Contact" button, it opens phone contact book from where i can select any contact for whom i want to send a custom msg. I am displaying the selected contacts in ListView and i want the selected contact/contacts to get save in SQLite Database so that if app or phone restarts the selected contacts remain there unless deleted.

Comment: @laalto  i am able to get the data String contactData = selectedContactList.get(arg2).toString(). But i don't know how that contactData to SQLite